# Как записать выражение в тип данных datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table tome (created_at  datetime2 )
insert into users("created_at") values('2018-12-06 00:20:11.835')
```

При попытке записи даты и времени   выдаёт ошибку 
Сообщение 273, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 2
Не удалось вставить явное значение в столбец отметки времени. Используйте INSERT со списком столбцов, чтобы исключить столбец отметки времени, либо вставьте DEFAULT в столбец отметки времени.

Comment: Если  у вас заменить `insert into users` на `insert into tome`, то все отлично [работает](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dd894/1)

Comment: Тип timestamp я взял из сообщения об ошибке, потому что insert вы делаете не в ту таблицу, которую создаете в предыдущем запросе, так что тип данных там может быть любым. Если же предположить, что это одна и та же таблица, то ошибка не воспроизводиться http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dd894/2

Comment: спасибо, вопрос решён

Comment: Ну так опишите, как вы его решили